# Cypress component testing with nuxt2 and mapFields

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, cypress, vuex-map-fields

I'm trying to write tests for a vue/2nuxt2 application, but in this aplication i use **...mapFields** from [vuex-map-fields](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields) to access the stores i have.

The problem is when mounting the component, cypress try to access the store via mapFields, and crashes. I try to "stub" the mapFields function, but it crashes anyway.

Is there a form to access the nuxt store, or to snub/mock mapFields ?

```js
beforeEach(() => {
     const mapFieldsStub = cy.stub(mapFieldsModule, 'mapFields')
     mapFieldsStub.returns(true)
     mount(this._component, this.opts)
   })
```

The options i use to mount it, the global methods i can mock, but not "mapFields".

```js
this.opts = {
      plugins: [ElementUI],
      mocks: {
        $t: (msg) => {
          const langPath = opts.langFileName ? this.removeLangFilePath(msg, opts.langFileName) : this.removeLangFilePath(msg, 'common')
          const langObject = opts.langs ? opts.langs.default : langs.default
          return this.refDotNotation(langObject, langPath.substring(1))
        },
        $const: (msg) => {
          return this.refDotNotation(opts.constants.default, msg)
        }
      },
      propsData: { value: '' },

      ...opts
    }
```

[image: error from cypress]